# Would like to destroy the stack that I made

Tags: c++, class, destructor, abstract-data-type

So, in class, we learnt about the implementation of an array abstract data structure, and using the array class we made, we implemented a stack abstract data structure as a class.

```
#include <iostream>
#ifndef ARRAYADT1_H
#define ARRAYADT1_H

using namespace std;

class ArrayADT1
{
    public:
        ArrayADT1();
        ArrayADT1(int);
        virtual ~ArrayADT1();
        bool setElement(int, int);
        int getElement(int);
        int getCapacity();
    protected:

    private:
        int capacity;
        int* elements;

};

#endif // ARRAYADT1_H


ArrayADT1::ArrayADT1(){
    capacity=0;
    elements=NULL;
}

ArrayADT1::ArrayADT1(int arraySize){
    capacity=arraySize;
    elements=new int[arraySize];
}

bool ArrayADT1::setElement(int index, int value){
    elements[index]=value;
    return(true);
}

int ArrayADT1::getElement(int index){
    return(elements[index]);
}

int ArrayADT1::getCapacity(){
    return(capacity);
}

ArrayADT1::~ArrayADT1(){
    delete[] elements;
}
```

```
#ifndef STACKADT1_H
#define STACKADT1_H

using namespace std;

class StackADT1
{
    public:
        StackADT1()=delete; //disable creation of stack without specifying capacity
        StackADT1(int); //create stack of capacity
        bool push(int);
        int pop();
        bool isFull();
        bool isEmpty();
        int length();
        virtual ~StackADT1();

    protected:

    private:
        int ValueCount;
        ArrayADT1 members;

};

#endif // STACKADT1_H

#include <iostream>

StackADT1::StackADT1(int stackCapacity): members(stackCapacity){
    ValueCount=0;
}

int StackADT1::length(){
    return(ValueCount);
}

bool StackADT1::isEmpty(){
    if(ValueCount==0)
        return(true);
    return(false);
}

bool StackADT1::isFull(){
    if(ValueCount==members.getCapacity())
        return(true);
    return(false);
}

int StackADT1::pop(){
    if(isEmpty()){
        cout<<"The Stack is empty"<<"\n";
        return(-1);
    }
    ValueCount--;
    return(members.getElement(ValueCount));
}

bool StackADT1::push(int value){
    if(isFull()){
        cout<<"The stack is full"<<"\n";
        return(false);
    }
    members.setElement(ValueCount, value);
    ValueCount++;
    return(true);
}

StackADT1::~StackADT1(){
    //I would like to know what happens here
    //dtor



}
```

I was wondering about the destructor function in both cases. In the ArrayADT1 class, we explicitly used the delete method, but we do no such thing in the StackADT1 class. Does the stack also get destroyed after

```
return 0;
```

is called?

Comment: pair `new` with `delete`, `StackADT1` doesn't use `new` so it doesn't need to call `delete` either

Comment: it is refreshing to see memory managment thaught not completely wrong. Your code is a nice example of seperating memory managmenment into a class that does nothing but that and the actual stack class doesnt need to worry about messing around manually with `new` nor `delete`

Comment: `ArrayADT1` should implement Rule of five, after that `Stack` gets all its functionality for free. Also consider making ctors with one argument explicit.

Comment: Free gratuitous code review https://godbolt.org/z/Ta96xhf3K

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the ArrayADT1 class, we explicitly used the delete method, but we do no such thing in the StackADT1 class

You also explicitly used the new-expression in ArrayADT1 class, but you don't use a new-expression in the StackADT1. This is to be expected, since we only delete what we new.

> ```
> //I would like to know what happens here
> //dtor
> ```

Nothing happens in the body of that destructor because the body is empty. The destructor will destroy the sub objects after the (empty) body.

---

`ArrayADT1` is copyable, but copying it results in undefined behaviour. This is bad. To fix it, follow the rule of five. I also recommend studying the RAII idiom. The example program appears to be a flawed attept at implementing RAII.

Next, I recommend learning about `std::unique_ptr` which is a better way to manage memory.